# Python optimize packets in sending. How to prevent it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, tcp

Im trying to send 3 packets one after the other with python socket.
Python optimize it to one or 2 packets.
I prevented it by sleep command, but it takes too long time.
I thought to turn on the TCP urg flag, Does someone know how to do it?

or you have another solotion?

client side:

```
import socket
from time import sleep

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5081
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((IP, PORT))

s.send('1'*5)
#sleep( 1)
s.send('2'*5)
#sleep( 1)
s.send('3'*5)

s.close()
```

server side:

```
import socket

IP = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 5081
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((IP, PORT))
s.listen(1)

connection, address = s.accept()
while 1:
    #Here I expected to get the 1nd value
    data1 = connection.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    #end of communication
    if not data1:
        break
    print 'data1', data1

    #Here I expected to get the 2nd value,but both inputs arrived here, 22222 and 33333
    data2  = connection.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print 'data2', data2

    #Here I expected to get the 3nd value
    data3  = connection.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    print 'data3', data3

connection.close()
```

thanks 
Avinoam

Comment: Why do you expect to get 5 bytes when you set the buffer size to 1024?

Comment: disable NAGLE algorithm: `s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)`

Comment: @thebjorn - `recv` takes a maximum buffer size but is quite happy to return much smaller blocks if that's all that's in the socket's receive buffer. It doesn't wait for 1024 bytes.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - that's not enough to stop aggregation of buffers. TCP is a streaming protocol and will collapse buffers on both the sender and receiver side.

Comment: @tdelaney: you are right about buffers (in-app or in-kernel) but the question was about packets (on the wire). With disabling NAGLE the senders kernel will at least try to send the data immediately as a packet and not wait for more data. But if there are still data to be send in the in-kernel socket buffer (outstanding ACK, small window...) it will of course merge the new data with the still unsent data. Of course TCP is streaming so you cannot use send/recv to handle a messages by its own but you need to implement your own encapsulation for messages.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich - Sure, the kernel will try to send data immediately as a packet but there are a dozen reasons why the data can be aggregated anyway. My comment was a warning that even if this snippet may appear to work with Nagle disabled, in general it will end in tears.

Answer (score 5):

You should not even try. TCP is a stream protocol and should be used as a stream protocol (meaning a single sequence of bytes). Even if you manage to maintain the separation of packets when you use localhost on *your* system, it could break if you use it between different hosts, or simply after an upgrade of the TCP/IP stack. And as soon as your packets will pass through a proxy or a software filter, anything can happen.

The correct way to separate different *objects* on a stream is to use an upper level protocol encoding the objects sender side and decoding them client side. An example of that is one or two bytes (in network order if more than one byte) for the size followed by the relevant bytes. Or you could imagine a text protocol with commands, headers and data, or [put whatever you want here]

Comment: A switch will not change the packet. A router might fragment the TCP packet at the IP layer but will not cause change of the TCP packet size since the IP fragments are reassembled in the kernel at the IP layer (i.e. below TCP) too. But things like a proxy might cause changes at higher layers and thus change packet size. Also MTU setting and PMTU  might influence packet size. Apart from that I fully agree with you, i.e. TCP should never be treated as a message protocol but only as a byte stream.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: Thanks for the comment. I've edited my post with it...